# Java - динамическое создание объектов класса в методе

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста! Пытаюсь динамически создавать новые объекты класса в процессе выполнения программы. 
Условно так:

```
public class FightRobot extands Robots {  .....   }
```

а далее в процессе выполнения программы при обработке нажатия кнопки

```
class ButtonEventListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String massage = "";
        massage += "Another FightRobot is created\n";
        massage += "Name is " + input.getText() + "\n";
```

и тут:

```
FightRobot ******* = new FightRobot(param);    //???????
```

Здесь нужно создать новый объект класса FightRobots по нажатию кнопки (естественно с уникальным именем объекта вместо звездочек) 
т.к. при каждом обращении к методу или при каждом нажатии кнопки должен создаваться новый объект класса

```
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,massage, "Output", 
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

}
}

Сколько не искал как динамически создавать объекты класса в методе после компиляции программы, так и не смог найти - помогите пожалуйста, кто в курсе

Comment: использование String как название массива и динамическое создание объектов класса из метода ведь не одно и тоже - List здесь уже не работает

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался!